# Java 8 Stream give default value to null elements

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of objects as shown below, want to give default value to the element where the number of hours is null

[java, 10 hours]
[python, 2 hours]
[node, 1 hour]
[c, null]  <--- NULL
[ruby, 4 hours]
[Swift, null]  <--- NULL
[php, 2 hours]

Expected:

[java, 10 hours]
[python, 2 hours]
[node, 1 hour]
[c, **defaultValue**]
[ruby, 4 hours]
[Swift, **defaultValue**]
[php, 2 hours]

Comment: Is stream required, wouldn't a for loop suffice?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `if` inside a map-statement to achieve what you desire:

```
List<String[]> newList = list.stream()
    .map(e-> {
        String newVal = e[1];
        if(newVal == null){
            newVal = "defaultValue";
        }
        return new String[]{e[0], newVal};
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you can see that i created a new array in the map operation. Which is prefered over editing the already existing one, because that way no side-effects happen.

> For more info about `map()` have a look at [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

But why not use a `foreach`-loop in the first place, that way it is easier to understand what you actually want to achieve, there is also no overhead in creating a `Stream`:

```
for(String[] e : list){
    if(e[1] == null){
         e[1] = "defaultValue";
    }
}
```

It is not always a good idea to just force yourself to use streams when you can just use good ol' loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String[]> list = Arrays.asList(
            new String[] {"java", "10 housrs"},
            new String[] {"python", null}
    );
    list.stream().filter(pair -> pair[1] == null).forEach(pair -> pair[1] = "default value");
    list.forEach(pair -> System.out.printf("%s => %s\n", pair[0], pair[1]));
```

==

```
java => 10 housrs
python => default value
```

Comment: Use `map` to avoid side effect

Comment: @Dummy Using map may change the order of the elements in the list.

Comment: From the original question, the order is clearly not a problem

Comment: @Dummy No need to make unnecessary assumption. :)

Comment: Then why did you assume the order is important in the first place? Congratulations, you played yourself

Comment: OK, more precisely put, this way covers the case even if the order matters.